# ¿Cómo implementar enrutado con react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Estoy comenzando con el tema de las SPA y React.js y no consigo dar con la tecla para la "navegación".
He implementado un esqueleto simple que simula si sitio de tipo "Admin" y no consigo poner el enrutado a funcionar. Estoy seguro de que es un tema de concepto. Pero es que no consigo verlo.
Desde ya, agradezco cualquier ayuda.
El código sería algo así:

```
//index.jsx
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

//app.jsx
import './assets/css/app.css';
const App = () => {
  return (
      <div className="grid-container">
        <Sidebar />
        <Layout />
      </div>);};

//sidebar.jsx
export const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">User profile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

//layout.jsx
import { Navbar } from './navbar';
import { Footer } from './footer';
import { Dashboard } from './dashboard';
import { Userprofile } from './user-profile';

export const Layout: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="content-area">
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

//dashboard.jsx
export const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {
  return <h3>Dashboard</h3>;
};
//navbar.jsx
export const Navbar = () => {return <div className="navbar">navbar</div>;};
//user-profile.jsx
export const Userprofile = () => {return <h3>Userprofile</h3>;};

//app.css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0; color: black; background-color: white; box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; }
.grid-container {display: grid;grid-template-columns: 240px 1fr; grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 50px;
  grid-template-areas:
    'sidebar navbar'
    'sidebar content-area'
    'sidebar footer';
  height: 100vh;
}
.navbar {grid-area: navbar; border: solid 1px green;}
.sidebar {grid-area: sidebar; border: solid 1px blue;}
.content-area {grid-area: content-area; border: solid 1px black;}
.footer {grid-area: footer; border: solid 1px red;}
```

La pregunta sería
¿cómo implementar una navegación básica para este escenario?

Comment: Pero que es lo que falla? Algún error? Algo que esta mostrando y no debería o viceversa?

Comment: que no consigo que funcione. No sé dónde poner los router, switch, etc para que la navegación sea correcta. Me cambia en la barra de direcciones pero no se muestran los componentes asociados